# Parsing an integer with XMLParser

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, parsing, nsxmlparser

I'm trying to parse an XML file, that file contains strings and integers.
So I defined a class, but when I try to assing the parsed value to one of the class's property which is an intenger I get "this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key aProperty"

aProperty is defined as: NSInteger aProperty;
I parse with NSXMLParser and I tried the following:

```
aClass.aProperty = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"aProperty"];

aClass.aProperty = [[attributeDict objectForkey:@"aProperty"] intValue];
```

Couldnt achieve what i wanted with either of those.

the property is written in the xml file as:

```
<aClass>
<aProperty>12</aProperty>
</aClass>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSXMLParser's delegate will receive a `parser:foundCharacters:` message.  You just need to transform that those `foundCharacters` into a number.

```c
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    int x = [string intValue];
    //...
}
```